# Logging Authentication Attempts When Using MS Account Authentication in MVC

Tags: asp.net, security, logging, owasp

I'm working on an ASP.NET Web Application that has authentication set up using Azure AD.

When an unauthenticated user navigates to a page requiring authentication, they are redirected to a Microsoft login page that takes their Username/Password.

This is all good and works just like it says on the tin.

I want to be able to:

- Log all failed attempts at logging in.
- Log all *successful* logins

I can't find anyway of doing this or (unless I'm just looking in the wrong place) any indication that it even *can* be done.

I'm driven to add these log attempts after reading the OWASP Top Ten. I find it kinda hard to believe that MS have all of this code and there is no way to log what's going on.

Is there?

Comment: Do you want to log from the Azure AD side or from your application end , since you mention that you are working on ASP.NET MVC Web Application ?

Comment: From the app side, ideally.

Comment: There must be some WebHook which is provided by Azure AD and you may tie into it.